# HTML replace paragraphs and breaks

Tags: html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm using the `HTMLAgilityPack` to parse some HTML.  I'd like to replace all the `<p>` tags with `\r` and all the `<br>` tags with `\n`.  Not really sure how to do that, this is what I've tried so far:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var ptags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");

        foreach (var ptag in ptags)
        {
            ptag.OuterHtml.Replace("<p>", "\r");
        }

        var brtags = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br");

        foreach (var br in brtags)
        {
            br.OuterHtml.Replace("<br>", "\n");
        }
```

Comment: And it doesn't work? What is the problem..?

Answer (score 0):

this function works for me:

```
public string ReplaceParagraph(HtmlDocument doc)
{
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p")
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(pNode => pNode.InnerHtml = HtmlNode.CreateNode(pNode.InnerText + "\r").InnerHtml);
    return doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")
        .Aggregate("", (current, node) => current + (" " + node.InnerText)).TrimStart();
}
```

as an Unit test you can run something like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<p>line 1</p><p>line 2</p>");
var plainText = ReplaceParagraph(doc);
Assert.IsTrue(plainText == "line 1\r line 2\r", "not equal to expected string");
```

The same function ReplaceParagrap can be used to replace 
 tags with \n.